# Objective-C Category property not recognized

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a requirement for multiple tables in one view and to identify each, I've added a categroy on the UITableView with a property called "tableID"

Here is the category code

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UITableView (BrandsTView)
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *tableID;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "UITableView+BrandsTView.h"
@implementation UITableView (BrandsTView)
@dynamic tableID;
@end
```

In the view controller's initialization code I am setting the property as follows:

```
[self.hubTableView setTableID:@"tblHubBrands"];
```

When the code reaches the first of the table view delegate's methods, tableID is unrecognized and I get an error when trying to set tblID as follows:

NOTE: tableID is available in code completion at this point, so again assuming it would be recognized

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSString *tblID = [tableView tableID]; // error: unrecognized selector
    if([tblID isEqualToString:@"tblHubBrands"]){
        return [hubBrands count];
    } else {
        //
    }
}
```

Any idea what's going on here? I was assuming that the tableID property should be available in any class that imported the category.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have pointed out, you can't add instance variables to a class in a category.

I've tackled the problem of managing multiple table views by using the pointer to the table view at runtime. I save pointers to both table views as IBOutlets, and then in my code for the table view data source and delegate methods (which all take a pointer to the table view as their first parameter) I check to see which table view is calling me and act accordingly.

e.g.:

The VC's header might contain the following:

```
@interface MyTwoTableViewVC: UIViewController;
{
  IBOutlet UITableView* firstTableView;
  IBOutlet UITableView* secondTableView;
}
@end
```

And the implementation for a data source method might look like this:

```
@implementation MyTwoTableViewVC
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if (tableView == firstTableView)
     //return the number of rows in section for the first table view
  else if (tableView == secondTableView)
     //return the number of rows in section for the second table view
  else
     //error. We only have 2 table views!
}
```

This method essentially uses the address of the table view as it's ID. At runtime the address of the table view won't change, so it works well.

If you're determined to add an ID property to your table views in a category, you can define an @dynamic property as you've done, then write custom getters and setters that use associative storage to read/write the ID value to the object at runtime. This is a bit of a hack, and kind of overkill for this problem, but it works.

The methods you want to look at are objc_getAssociatedObject()  and objc_setAssociatedObject().

I have an [**associative storage demo project**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/AssocitiveStorageDemo) on github (that's a link to the project.)

(That project uses a category of NSObject to add associative storage support to any NSObject at runtime.)

Answer (score 2):

> Categories can be used to declare either instance methods or class
>   methods but are not usually suitable for declaring additional
>   properties. It’s valid syntax to include a property declaration in a
>   category interface, but it’s not possible to declare an additional
>   instance variable in a category. This means the compiler won’t
>   synthesize any instance variable, nor will it synthesize any property
>   accessor methods. You can write your own accessor methods in the
>   category implementation, but you won’t be able to keep track of a
>   value for that property unless it’s already stored by the original
>   class.
>
> The only way to add a traditional property—backed by a new instance
>   variable—to an existing class is to use a class extension, as
>   described in “Class Extensions Extend the Internal Implementation.”

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: It is possible to add a synthesized property to an object using a category and then use associative storage to save the value, so you can get the same effect. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's because there is no `tableID` method declared on `UITableView`. What you did, is to declare a property, and then use `@dynamic`, to tell the compiler, that the accessor methods of that property are implemented elsewhere, but actually there are implemented nowhere.

Also, you can't add new ivars to an object using a Category (which you would need to add a working property). I recommend subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView inherits from UIView
Just set the tag property to something unique for each one. 
Even better, use NS_ENUM to define your own named constants to use for the tags. 
You can put the enum in a global constants .h file and import it anywhere. 
Now you have easy and fast identifiers with code completion and readable code. 
If you need a string value to display somewhere that's easy enough to return strings based on a simple switch statement checking the tag. 
You can even return strings using the localizable strings functions.

Comment: In other words don't make it more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can add properties to a category using associated objects. You can read more [here](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/).
That being said, in your case you should follow what suggested by other answers.